# Implementando relacionamento em C#

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, relacionamento, uml

Tenho as seguintes classes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código está assim:

```
public class Mae
{
   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public List<Filho> Filhos {get; set;}
}
public class Filho
{
   public string Nome {get; set;}
}
```

Neste caso, é possível obter todos os *filhos da mãe*, mas não é possível obter a mãe dos filhos.

Ex.:

```
var mae = new Mae();
mae.Nome = "Maria";
mae.Filho = new List<Filho>();

var filho = new Filho();
filho.Nome = "Joãozinho"

mae.Filho.Add(filho);

filho.Mae // O objetivo é acessar a mãe...
```

Como seria possível fazer isso?

Comment: Qual a ideia? Usar Entity Framework?

Comment: Não @CiganoMorrisonMendez , estou criando as classes na mão mesmo. Mas eu queria o funcionamento semelhante ao Entity Framework, pois achei muito lindo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A única forma é ter uma referência para a mãe:

```
public class Mae {
   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public List<Filho> Filhos {get; set;} = new List<Filho>(); //C# 6
}
public class Filho {
   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public Mae Mae {get; set;}
}
```

Tem como criar algumas abstrações. Você pode criar construtores ou outros métodos auxiliares que automatizam um pouco o processo. Se todo filho tem que ter uma mãe, pode garantir isto no construtor e pode inclusive já fazer a inclusão do filho na mãe.

```
public class Filho {
   public Filho(String nome, Mae mae) {
       Nome = nome;
       Mae = mae;
       mae.Filho.Add(this);
   }
   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public Mae Mae {get; set;}
}

var filho = new Filho("João", mae);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Relationship.cs).

[Veja sobre construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Comment: mas assim, ao criar o filho eu tenho que apontar quem é a mãe, correto?

Comment: Sim, eu editei para deixar isto mais claro. Dá até para fazer de um jeito um pouco diferente, mas não tem como escapar disto. Faz até sentido fazer desta forma. Se por acaso o Filho puder ficar sem uma mãe, tem que fazer alguma adaptação para permitir isto.

Comment: No modelo descrito na sua pergunta, @JedaiasRodrigues, a definição de dependência é clara - não pode existir um `Filho` sem a propriedade `Mae`. Neste caso a maneira como bigown especificou está correta.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues fique atento aos construtores. Se deseja garantir o estado inicial do objeto. Até poderia usar contrato para garantir que o estado sempre estará em ordem. Mas isto é mais avançado e poucos fazem. Você poderia fazer algumas outras coisas. Se a mão não pode ser trocada, então tire o `set;` da propriedade. Poderia fazer o mesmo para o nome, se fizer sentido para seu modelo.

Comment: obrigado @bigown este foi só uma adaptação de um exemplo para que eu pudesse entender o conceito... Mas uma última dúvida. Ao criar um Filho eu teria uma segunda estância da Mãe na memória, ou seria usado o mesmo objeto Mãe instanciado antes?

Comment: Se fizer como está na última linha (considerando que a variável `mae` já é uma instância de `Mae`, conforme o seu exemplo, não será criada nada novo. Evidentemente que se usar `var filho = new Filho("João", new Mae {Nome = "Maria"});` vai criar uma nova instância de `Mae`, e pior, como não guardará em nenhuma variável, ela ficará inacessível de forma direta (poderá ser acessada através do seu filho).

Answer (score 1):

Adicione uma referência para `Mae` no filho. Se for uma dependência, coloque como parâmetro no construtor do filho.

Segue exemplo:

```
public class Mae
{
   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public List<Filho> Filhos {get; set;}
}

public class Filho
{
   public Filho(Mae mae)
   {
        this.Mae = mae;
   }

   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public Mae Mae {get; set;}
}
```